# .htaccess multiple domain with different location

Tags: .htaccess

I have multiple domains

- a.example.com
- b.exampe.com

Rewrite condition :

- a.example.com will be used to public/index.php
- b.example.com will be used tojobs

If I use Nginx, I can use alias. How about using.htaccess? is it possible?
my current .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?a.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^//jobs/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /jobs/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^b.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

The rewrite condition with a.example.com is not working

Comment: It should be done by config two vhost

Comment: im using azure webapps, is it possibe?

Comment: yes, just split it in two webapp

Comment: It doesn't make sense to split up into two apps, by default azure webapps will be pointed the apache configuration to /home/wwwroot/sites

On /home/wwwroot/sites , i need to 2 domain with :
1. open the apps automatically in /home/wwwroot/sites/public/index.php 
2. open the apps automatically in in /home/wwwroot/sites/jobs